# Failing to load overlay in xul application

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner, xpi

I have a stand-alone xulrunner application, that needs extension to work properly. But after I install xpi file, my jsconsole is reporting me an error `"Failed to load overlay from chrome://my-client/content/overlays/index.xul"`. That means that `chrome.manifest` file is recognized, but the path to overlay is not good.

My chrome.manifest file in xpi

```
content my-client file:chrome//
overlay chrome://app/content/lib/conf.xul chrome://my-client/content/overlays/index.xul
```

Id of extension in `install.rdf` file is the same as the id in `application.ini` file of the main application. I have enabled extension manager

```
[XRE]
EnableExtensionManager=1
```

And I have extension.js file in my prefs.

The weird part is when I just symlink folder of my-client extension into extension folder in my main application everything works just as i expect. This only occurs when i install xpi through extension manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that I forgot to put this line of code in my `install.rdf` file

```
<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
```

documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Install_Manifests#unpack